# Query an attribute of many to many object in django

Tags: python, django

In my Django Model I want to query a many to many related object and get value of another attribute

Models.py

```
class FlowKits(models.Model):
    kit = models.ForeignKey(Kit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trip_cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Flow(models.Model):
    flow_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    kits = models.ManyToManyField(FlowKits)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I get the `trip_cost` of a flow whose flow_name = 'Foo' and kit = 'bar'?

I got the `Flow` object but how to proceed?

```
t = Flow.objects.get(flow_name = 'Foo')
```

Comment: I assume `Kit` has a `name` field or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

t = Flow.objects.filter(flow_name = 'Foo',kits__kit__name='bar').annotate(trip_cost = Sum('kits__trip_cost'))

# Here I am assuming you have name field in kit.
```